# Python 3 "Evolving" Code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wanted to try to make an evolving code, you know, just to see if I could.

Long story short, I couldn't.

```
__author__ = 'kim'
import random
import string
import fileinput
import os



#Random letter
random_letter = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
print(random_letter)
#Other Random Letter
other_random_letter = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
print(other_random_letter)

for line in fileinput.input("file.py", inplace=True):
    print(line.replace(other_random_letter, random_letter), end='')

os.system("python3 file.py")
```

What i want to do is to replace a random amount of code with gibberish. if the code crashed it would copy from a file called fallsafe.py and replace the file file.py

Comment: OK, but what is wrong with the code you have here?  What *question* are you asking about this code?

Comment: It does not copy, because I don't know how.

Comment: [`shutil.copyfile()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfile).

Comment: OK, but what if i want only to do that if it crashs

Comment: Check the return value of `os.system` and write an `if` statement.

Comment: Why don't you exec the code with exec or eval instead of saving it and opening another python interpreter?

Comment: Because I'm not good at coding python and are trying to learn. but how do i do those 2 things?
EDIT: Grammar

Comment: Ehm I'll add an answer because its prettier to write code there...

Comment: OK, Thanks. And also how do i make it replace F.E: 2 to 8 letters at a time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it with exec:

```
import random
import string

code = ''

for i in range(1000): #1000 iterations
    if random.randint(0, 1):
        code += random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
    else:
        code = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)

    try:
        print ('trying code: ' + code)
        exec(code)
    except:
        print('It crashed... adding another letter... it will surely work now!')
```

Now, let me tell you this will never work, it is virtually impossible that it will produce a meaningful line of code (btw you should include spaces too in random.choice).

I know what you wanna do and I've done it before, but you need a special Virtual Machine, with one byte commands, so that way is easier to produce valid code.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I make it replace the letter**s** when it crashes not just add new? and how do I make it either add or replace?

Comment: Well you can do that with if random.randint(0, 1): //add character else: //replace line

Comment: also pycharm says that "eval code" isn't a thing

Comment: ehm thats python2.7 code, you want python3? lemme update

Comment: another question, what file is this editing. is it editing it self?

Comment: well no, its creating a variable, and running the code inside that variable

Comment: can I make that variable sync to a file?

Comment: well yes haha, just do open('out', 'w').write(code)

Comment: Thanks so much, this is what I wanted. but what the heck is open('out', 'w').write(code) . I Googled it but nothing came up. but if i could vote i'd vote you

Comment: Oh sorry, i figured out open('out', 'w').write(code) . sorry. but good answars :D

Comment: oh, one last thing, where should i put this?  if random.randint(0, 1): //add character else: //replace line